# vim-snippets: placeholders with same name are not replaced all at once

Tags: vim, code-snippets

I'm trying to create snippets that should write the same text in several different places:

```
import ${0:Class} from './${0:Class}'

export default ${0:Class}
```

In this case, when expanding it, the cursor to enter a text will somehow be selected on `default`, and will only edit in one place.

```
import from './'

export [default] // -> cursor highlights "default" for replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

Which plugin are you using?

[Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) does support it:

```
import ${0:Class} from './$0'

export default $0
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't not work. The other two placeholders will have "Class" written, but changing the first one doesn't change the others.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 I'm not sure which plugin you're using. I guess it's probably `snipmate`. Consider upgrading to Ultisnips. It's completely compatible with `snipmate`, and the feature requested is supported.

Comment: This is odd because I remember being able to do it once, and I had problems with Ultisnips.

Comment: Yes, that should be the right syntax for snipmate. However, I think you have to name the first placeholder `1` instead of `0`.